# How to disabled multiple checkbox selection in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, dom-events

I have a list of items where the user able to select one item at a time, For example, if a user selects one row then I want to disabled other rows I want to be select one row at a time. I really tried hard but didn't able to resolve this issue.

**Code**

```
{menus.map((item,index)=>(<input type="checkbox value={index} />)}
```

Comment: Use Radio button.

Comment: @AjeetShah Actually, there is some requirement to use checkbox

Comment: What is the specific requirement that enforces the use of a check-box?

Comment: @Craig Yes, I need to be use check-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can use the `checked` attribute along with `onChange` to make a controlled checkbox.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [selItem, setSelItem] = useState(null);
  const handleChange = (item) => {
    item === selItem ? setSelItem(null) : setSelItem(item);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label>
        Apple
        <input type="checkbox" checked={selItem === "Apple"} onChange={() => handleChange("Apple")} />
      </label>
      <label>
        Mango
        <input type="checkbox" checked={selItem === "Mango"} onChange={() => handleChange("Mango")} />
      </label>
      <label>
        Banana
        <input type="checkbox" checked={selItem === "Banana"} onChange={() => handleChange("Banana")} />
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

### More elaborate example

You can have a `isChecked` property on your menu items and then you can control the checkboxes using this property.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [menus, setMenus] = useState([
    { id: 1, label: "Apple", isChecked: false },
    { id: 2, label: "Mango", isChecked: false },
    { id: 3, label: "Banana", isChecked: false },
  ]);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setMenus(
      menus.map((o) =>
        o.id == e.target.value ? { ...o, isChecked: !o.isChecked } : { ...o, isChecked: false }
      )
    );
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {menus.map((item) => (
        <label key={item.id}>
          {item.label}
          <input type="checkbox" checked={item.isChecked} value={item.id} onChange={handleChange} />
        </label>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want select one row at a time. You can use a state to control this:

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState();

  const onClick = (e) => {
    setChecked(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {menus.map((item, index) => (
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          value={index}
          checked={index == checked}
          onClick={onClick}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
```

Comment: With this approach the user will never be able to unselect all checkboxes after one checkbox is selected.